# mongodb - date comparison doesn't work in aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following aggregation:

```
db.runCommand(
  {"aggregate":"Order","pipeline":[
    {"$match":{"shopId":28440395907}},
    {"$match":{"createdAt":{"$gte":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"0"}}}}},
    {"$sort":{"updatedAt":-1}},
    {"$facet":{"results":[{"$skip":0},{"$limit":25}],"count":[{"$count":"count"}]}}
  ],"allowDiskUse":true,"cursor":{}}
);
```

The problem is that it fails to return any results. Replacing the date filter with literally anything else provides results so my guess is that there is a problem with date conversion. I tried all the versions I found in tutorials (like new Date("2015-06-17 10:03:46.000Z")), it always acts the same. Can anyone please explain why and how to fix?

Comment: try `{ $match: { createdAt: { $gte: new Date(1607614920000) } } }`

Comment: Why do you use `runCommand()` instead of plain `db.Order.aggregate([...])`?

Comment: Did you try `{$gte: ISODate("2015-06-17T10:03:46Z")}`?

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit that one works. Post it as an answer pls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date format is wrong, use the format according to ISO-8601:

```
new Date("2015-06-17T10:03:46Z")
```

or

```
ISODate("2015-06-17T10:03:46Z")
```

`ISODate()` is an alias for `new Date()` you have in the mongo shell.

Format `2015-06-17 10:03:46Z` is commonly used but not compliant to ISO-8601 standard if you like to specify a time at a certain day.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in aggregation in mongodb the date is stored always in format numberLong and that last doesn't fit to be compared cause the numberLong also doesn't stored as a number but as a string for example: { createdAt: new Date('2023-03-05') } will be stored like { "createdAt" : { "$date": {"$numberLong: "1677974400000" <-- string and not a number } } } and therefore the comparison return always a null result ([]), and from here I suggest another solution that worked form me, the idea is very simple, we added a new field named "dateCreation" which is the result of converting the date "createdAt" to a double then we'll be able to use it for comparison as shown below :

```js
db.runCommand(
  {"aggregate":"Order","pipeline":[
    {"$match":{"shopId":28440395907}},
    {"$addFields":{"dateCreation":{"$toDouble": "$createdAt"}}},
    {"$match":{"dateCreation":{"$gte":0}}},
    {"$sort":{"updatedAt":-1}},
    {"$facet":{"results":[{"$skip":0},{"$limit":25}],"count":[{"$count":"count"}]}}
  ],"allowDiskUse":true,"cursor":{}}
);
```

I know the question is old and it's been over 2 years but I haven't found a way that works with aggregation except for this one